# Scipy: Convergence Metrics

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm using scipy's [Basin Hopping algorithm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping) to optimize a multivariate cost function. Temperature is one of the parameters that greatly affects convergence time of the basin hopping algorithm. I would like to be able to determine how quickly `basinhopping()` is converging by fitting the cost function value curve up to the current iteration and determining if it's a faster convergence than the previous temperature setting.

Here's what the basin hopping call looks like:

```
res = basinhopping(cost, guess, niter=1, T=t, minimizer_kwargs={"method": "cobyla"})
```

Is there some way to get "live" updates on the current value of the cost function so that I can do an adaptive optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to find an optimal T,
by e.g. 
[Golden_section_search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_section_search)
on the function of one variable:

```
ftemperature( T ) = basinhopping( ... T=T ... ) .func  ?
```

If so, build up history lists of `func` `T` and `res` that feed  your `Tsearch` function:

```
# initialize history lists for a few T  (grid search) --
fhist, Thist, reshist = [], [], []

for T in [...]:
    res = basinhopping( cost, guess, T=T ... )
    print "T %.3g  func %.3g" % (T, res.func)
    fhist.append( res.func )
    Thist.append( T )
    reshist.append( res )

# search for new T --
while True:
    T = Tsearch( Thist, fhist )  # golden search or ...
    if T is None:  break
    res = basinhopping( cost, guess, T=T ... )
    print "T %.3g  func %.3g" % (T, res.func)
    fhist.append( res.func )
    Thist.append( T )
    reshist.append( res )
```

If not, please clarify.

(You could do the same thing inside `callback`s, as @Jacob Stevenson says.)

(There are fancier methods for minimizing functions of one variable, see e.g.
[scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar.html)
.)

Comment: Hi @denis, it's a function of many variables. Thanks for the response!

Comment: @nick_name, I'd suggest start small: vary T alone, and see how that changes results.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but the basinhopping parameter `callback` sounds like what you're looking for.

On a side note, what you're trying to do sounds a bit similar in concept to this paper [Freeze-Thaw Bayesian Optimization](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3896)